# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, slf4j

I know this has been asked many times, but none of the answers were satisfactory. Please excuse for creating this thread again.

I am writing a java program to convert XML to ISO:8583.

I am using **"slf4j-api-1.7.21.Jar"** and "j8583-1.11.0.jar".

**Here is my code:**

```
public class ExampleISOParser {

        private static BufferedReader reader;

        private static String getMessage() throws IOException {
            if (reader == null) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            }
            System.out.println("Paste your ISO8583 message here (no ISO headers): ");
            return reader.readLine();
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        try
        {
            final MessageFactory<IsoMessage> mf = new MessageFactory<IsoMessage>();
            if (args.length == 0) {
                ConfigParser.configureFromDefault(mf);
            } else {
                if (System.console() != null) {
                    System.console().printf("Attempting to configure MessageFactory from %s...%n", args[0]);
                }
                String url = args[0];
                if (url.contains("://")) {
                    ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new URL(args[0]));
                } else {
                    ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new File(url).toURI().toURL());
                }
            }
            //Now read messages in a loop
            String line = getMessage();
            while (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
                IsoMessage m = mf.parseMessage(line.getBytes(), 0);
                if (m != null) {
                    System.out.printf("Message type: %04x%n", m.getType());
                    System.out.println("FIELD TYPE    VALUE");
                    for (int i = 2; i <= 128; i++) {
                        IsoValue<?> f = m.getField(i);
                        if (f != null) {
                            System.out.printf("%5d %-6s [", i, f.getType());
                            System.out.print(f.toString());
                            System.out.println(']');
                        }
                    }
                }
                line = getMessage();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

       }


}
```

While running I get error : 
**SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".**

On googling I found that it has something to do with Maven.

But I am not sure how this is related to Maven, even though I tried to convert it into Maven project in Eclipse, still I am facing issue.

**This is all I am getting in stacktrace.**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I tried debugging and found that below is the line which is causing error.

final MessageFactory mf = new MessageFactory();

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: I have updated the detail. Also " final MessageFactory<IsoMessage> mf = new MessageFactory<IsoMessage>();" this is the line which is causing error

Comment: Do you have a log4j.properties file in your classpath?

Comment: It is there:  " <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/working/paymentmessage/lib/j8583-1.11.0.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/working/paymentmessage/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar"/>"

Comment: No that are the jar files. not the configuration file!!!

Comment: Did you have a look at the link you received with the error ?

Comment: sl4j is an _interface_, it requires an implementation like logback or log4j. [Reading the manual is a big help](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including "slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar" in classpath and external reference libraries solved the issue.